# How do I add a body of text above a slideshow without pushing it down?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I've created a slideshow inside a section tag using a div tag. I tried to add a body of text above the slideshow so I added another div tag above the div tag for the slideshow and it worked however, as I add text, it pushes the images in the slideshow down, cutting off the images in the slideshow. Is there a solution to this? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head> 
            <title> AnimeExpoBd </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
            <body>
                    <header>   
                                <ul>
                                        <li class="logo"><a href="index.html">ANIME EXPO LOGO</a></li>
                                        <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                        <li class="navbar"><a href=#gotoaboutus>ABOUT US</a></li> 
                                        <li class="navbar"><a href="moreaboutus.html">SCHEDULE</a></li>
                                        <li class="navbar"><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
                                </ul>                               
                    </header>
                    <section class="feature-box opening">
                        <div id="gotoaboutus" class="about-us"><strong>ABOUT US</strong><p class="descpara">We aim to popularize and educate the Bangladesh public about Japanese anime and manga culture, as well as provide a forum to facilitate communication between professionals and fans. We're passionate about all things anime. We're here to help you discover hidden gems, learn more about new and current anime, find fan art and cosplay of all your faves, and get your opinions!</div>
                        <div class="Images"></div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="feature-box closing">
                            <div class="sched">Section A<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque exercitationem ad sed enim maiores cum recusandae numquam quibusdam. Perferendis reiciendis ut tenetur dignissimos neque hic impedit optio quasi libero sunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, ipsum? Exercitationem accusantium quaerat numquam architecto cum culpa magnam illo quos quod. Eligendi placeat repellendus perferendis veritatis ducimus iure maxime vero! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae rerum quia odit veniam natus consequuntur iste eum eos officiis ab optio sed itaque quasi possimus voluptatibus, velit est dolor quo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat nostrum in, quidem totam a atque obcaecati natus ratione quae rem ipsam sed hic laudantium enim aspernatur nemo cum, nobis eius.</p></div>
                            <div class="slidershow middle">
                                <div class="header">Header and Description</div>      
                                <div class="slides">
                                    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked>
                                    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2">
                                    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r3">
                                    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r4">
                                    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r5">

                                     <div class="slide s1">
                                        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="images/3.png" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slide">
                                        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="navigation">
                                    <label for="r1" class="bar"></label>
                                    <label for="r2" class="bar"></label>
                                    <label for="r3" class="bar"></label>
                                    <label for="r4" class="bar"></label>
                                    <label for="r5" class="bar"></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </section>
                    <footer>footer</footer>
            </body>
</html>
```

```
section.feature-box.closing {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 620px;
    width: 1310px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    display: flex;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.slidershow div.header {
    font-size: medium;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.sched {
    width: 481px;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    font-size: medium;
    background-color: #c3edea;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.slidershow {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 68%;
    left: 31%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
section.feature-box.closing div.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
}   
section.feature-box.closing div.navigation label.bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.navigation label.bar:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
input[name="r"]{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.slides {
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-size: 100%;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.slides div.slide {
    width: 20%;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
section.feature-box.closing div.slides div.slide img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#r1:checked ~ .s1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#r2:checked ~ .s1 {
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#r3:checked ~ .s1 {
    margin-left: -40%;
}
#r4:checked ~ .s1 {
    margin-left: -60%;
}
#r5:checked ~ .s1 {
    margin-left: -80%;
}
```

Comment: can you share your working code

Comment: I've added the code @HimanshuSingh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
section.feature-box.closing div.slidershow div.header {
    font-size: medium;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: I've tried as you instructed and the issue was solved however I made a really big mistake and wouldn't have realized it without your help! I added the div tag for the text into the slideshow div which was causing the issue. I've solved it! Thank you very much :)